# How to figure out which value is 0?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, arithmeticexception, dividebyzeroexception

I got my 1st crash report for my app. It says there is a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero`

The exception is on one of these two lines:

```
//sWP stands for "Screen Width in Pixels"
// sW stands for "Screen Width" The code is old though, so I may be incorrect for both variables.
//res is just getResources()
int sWP = sW / (res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
float bHeight = 50 * ((float)res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
```

Can `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT` ever be zero? Or can `getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi` ever be zero?

Answer (score 0):

`res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi` will be 120, 160 or 240 (or something similar), see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#densityDpi.

`DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT` constantly equals 160, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_DEFAULT.

`res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT` will return 0 because you divide int by int.

**Change the first of the two lines to**

`int sWP = (int) sW / (((double) res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);`

**and it should work.**

Comment: Should I also change sWP to double? Also in this case res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi equals 320

Comment: @Roymunson Changing sWP to double does not make sense to me as you say _//sWP stands for "Screen width in Pixels"_. I am sorry, I forgot to cast to int. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Roymunson As to the value of 320 you get for densityDpi, somebody forgot to change the documentation for densityDpi from API 4 when introducing DENSITY_XHIGH in API 9.